# Google Structured Data Testing Tool only shows PostalAddress, not Dentist

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

With the Google rich snippet testing tool I can see valid markup code for postal address. But it doesn't show anything about the Dentist mark up, not even an error:

```html
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Dentist" itemprop="Brand">DOTT. xxxxxx</p>
<p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="streetAddress">...address....</span>     
<span itemprop="postalCode">xxxxx</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">xxxxx</span>
<br>tel/fax: <span itemprop="telephone">0000000</span>
<br>email: <a href="mailto:info@xxxxxx.com" 
itemprop="email">info@xxxxxx.com</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this supposed to be the address of the dentist? If yes, you have to nest the element with the `address` property in the element with the `Dentist` type:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Dentist">

  <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <!-- … -->
  </p>

</div>
```

If you do this, the Google Structured Data Testing Tool recognizes the `Dentist` item.

In your example, the `Dentist` item is the value of a `Brand` property (`itemprop="Brand"`). Note that this property does not exist: [`Brand`](http://schema.org/Brand) is a type (but [`brand`](http://schema.org/brand) is a property; URIs are case-sensitive). As your example misses the parent type, I can’t say if using the `brand` property is appropriate here.